# AJAX generates error when option is selected from the DropDownList in remote server

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0, asp.net-2.0

I am using Visual Studio 2005 [ASP.NET/C#].

I added `Script Manager`, `UpdatePanel` and `Content` in the master page. This Content tag encloses the contentPlaceHolder of the Master Page.

One of the content Form loads a Div with a Table enclosed in it. The Table has few DropDowns. Selecting an option from a DropDown fills the second DropDown.

My application is showing an error, while selecting an option from a DropDown and also when clicking the Submit button. It is showing error only on remote server but not when the application is run on Local Host.

The error is below:

[image]

**Edited**

I found that the following code was creating problems. After removing this code, everything is working. What is the problem with the below given code that cause the above mentioned error:

```
<location allowOverride="true" inheritInChildApplications="true">               <appSettings>
   <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />
   <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />
   <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />
</appSettings>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your HTML rendered in the response is corrupted by something. Look for HTTP Modules that work on the rendered response - maybe some regex based HTML alteration is going awry. Look also for Typos in the actual aspx page itself near the DOCTYPE tag.

In fact (just noticed) the error itself says why it may occur. If the error still persists paste the ASPX contents somewhere (mybe in [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/) or [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) ) and share a link here. Finally share in your question the list of HTTPModules that you are using on the remote server. Look for the list in IIS config, and in your web.config and in your remote servers machine.config. I suspect only the custom handwritten modules of causing the error - so leave out the .NET framework httpmodules.

Comment: What you have added to your post is a collection of settings for crystal reports framework Type CrystalImageCleaner whose job it is to clean the dynamically generated images at intervals. Singularly **unhelpful**.